# WS-Transaction Support

Tags: java, transactions, cxf

Trying to do some migrations of legacy applications (mainframe based) currently on IBM Websphere stack to open source. 
There are some complex XA transactions and there's also some WS transactions. I'm talking WS-Tx like spec. Got the XA covered with Atomikos, now evaluating CXF framework , is WS-Tx supported on CXF framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CXF doesn't support web service transactions. Axis2 supports the same , but is it needed.